# Can we get the text from the image using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, page-objects, eclipse

This is the path of the image from where I have to get the text shown on an image and into the text for security purposes,

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//img[@src=\"/register/tb135/tb_getimage.php?uid=1677953817&start=JTNFJTIy\"]")
    private WebElement textShown;
```

This is the XPath where I fill the shown text on the image,

```
@FindBy(id = "metric_iframe")
    private WebElement fillTextShown;
```

I tried to get the text using `textShown.getText()` but it failed. So what I suppose to get the text shown on the image?

Comment: What do you mean by "text from the image"? Are you talking about the alt text? Or the text written inside the image, as the text _Stack Exchange_ that appears on this website logo?

Comment: I was talking about the text written inside the image (not alt text ). But I also don't know how to get alt text from the image.

Comment: "text shown on an image and into the text for security purposes" - are you trying to bypass ReCaptcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to extract text directly from an image using Selenium. The `getText()` method retrieves the text content of a WebElement, but an image is not a text element.

However, you can use third-party `OCR (Optical Character Recognition)` libraries to extract text from an image. OCR technology is used to recognize text within images and convert it into machine-readable text. There are several OCR libraries available that can be integrated with your Selenium script to extract text from images.

One popular OCR library is `Tesseract OCR`, which is open-source and supports multiple languages. Here is an example of how you can use Tesseract OCR in your Selenium script to extract text from an image:

1 First, you need to download and install Tesseract OCR on your system.

2 Next, you can use the `getScreenshotAs()` method to take a screenshot of the image containing the text.

3 Then, you can pass this screenshot to Tesseract OCR for text extraction using the Tesseract OCR API.

4 Finally, you can retrieve the extracted text and use it in your test script.

5 Here is some sample code in Java that demonstrates how to use Tesseract OCR with Selenium:

```
// Import the necessary libraries
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

// Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

// Navigate to the page with the image
driver.get("https://example.com");

// Find the image element
WebElement imageElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src=\"/path/to/image.png\"]"));

// Take a screenshot of the image element
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Use Tesseract OCR to extract text from the image
ITesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
String text = tesseract.doOCR(screenshot);

// Output the extracted text
System.out.println(text);

// Close the browser
driver.quit();
```

Note that the above code is just an example and may need to be modified to suit your specific use case.